# systemd User= setting: how to apply selectively?

Tags: systemd

Systemd documentation says about User=:

This setting does not affect commands whose command line is prefixed with "+".
I was unable to use the "+" prefix. Anything I prefix with it is just ignored by system, so in the code below the pre-start will not run at all.

```
[Service]
+ExecStartPre=/postgres.run.sh pre_start
ExecStart=/postgres.run.sh
ExecStop=/postgres.run.sh stop
+ExecStopPost=/postgres.run.sh post_stop
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=postgres
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/pid.postgres
User=postgres
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right syntax, but the wrong `systemd` version. You are reading the docs for the current version of system, but running an older version. The `+ExecXYZ` syntax was introduced in `systemd` version 231.

The workaround is for your "service" to run as root and then have your scripts that need to run as `postgres` include `bash` wrappers that first `su` to PostgreSQL.

But why are you writing your own `postgresql` systemd file instead of using one already written?

Comment: yes, mine's 219 or something. I had it running wrapped in a sudo, but then the sudo is parented to 1, not the postgres, and then interesting things happen depending on which pid you feed to systemd as MainPID. I've figured it out now but running as postgres user was one way I tried to get rid of that situation. Didn't work - as you pointed out.